# Why aren't my Google preferences saving?

Tags: google-search

In Google Search preferences, there is an option to open search results in a new window. This has never ever worked for me, on any browser. Why?

Also, with the newer Google options on the lefthand sidebar, I have to click "more" and "more search tools" for every search. Why?

Comment: Are you logged in to a Google account? When you go back to the settings after saving them, is the checkbox still checked?

Comment: Yes, I am logged in.

Comment: No, the check box always unchecks, and if I change "number of results" it goes back to 10

Comment: it sounds like a problem with the browser (e.g. caching, cookies, or some other problem). You should try a different browser (just to see if that is indeed the issue), and if it is an issue with the browser, I would recommend asking the question on superuser.com.

Comment: An noted in [this question](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/7482/google-search-preferences-not-sticking-or-working-closed), this problem occurs for OP in different browsers as well (meaning it might not be a browser related issue).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Search, unlike the rest of the Google services, saves the setting to a client-side cookie, rather than a server-side profile. Every time the cookie gets deleted, your search preferences will be reset. This is done to allow the owner of the PC to determine search behavior (such as "safe search" options etc.) regardless of who's using the browser.

You might have a setting in your browser that cleans up cookies upon browser closing, or else, you may have a cleaning or privacy software (i.e. [CCleaner](http://www.filehippo.com/download_ccleaner/)) running regularly and removing your cookies.

My recommendation: either stop cleaning the cookies, or save the Google search cookie (it's a text file) and restore it every time you open your browser.